# Training and Testing dataset

Tags: dataset

I am fitting a glm model on my data set. But in my case I don't have any competing models to decide upon, i.e., I just have only one model and have to estimate the coefficients of the model. In such a case shouldn't I use all the data to train the model or should I still divide the data set into training and testing?

---

Also [cross-posted](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13877/training-and-testing-dataset) to the data science site.

Comment: Please don't cross post. It's bad.

Comment: @StudentT I made a similar comment on the other post, exemplifying the problems with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have competing models if you wanted. You could try elastic net, ridge, or a linear model.

You probably still want to have an idea of how your model performs on unseen data. This is the point of the training and test sets. So you do want to split the data.

Answer (score 0):

Training on a single GLM model is not an excuse for overfitting. You always should try to split unless you only really want to use the model on your training set.